# После первой итерации данные не записываются в БД

Tags: python, sqlite

После первого запуска программы всё работает хорошо, но при повторном запуске новые данные не вносятся в БД SQLite.

```
import sqlite3
import time
from os import system

con = sqlite3.connect("Server.db")
cur = con.cursor()

def autorize():
    system("CLS")
    print("Добро пожаловать в окно авторизации")
    login = input("Логин - ")
    password = input("Пароль - ")

    cur.execute("SELECT Login FROM Users WHERE Login = login")
    if cur.fetchone() is None:
        print("Данного аккаунта не существует\nЖелаете зарегистрироваться?")
        answer = input("Да/нет - ")
        if answer == "Да" or answer == "да":
            registration()
        elif answer == "Нет" or answer == "нет":
            autorize()
    else:
        pass


def registration():
    system("CLS")

    print("Добро пожаловать в окно регистрации")
    login = input("Логин - ")
    password = input("Пароль - ")

    cur.execute("SELECT Login FROM Users WHERE Login = login")
    if cur.fetchone() is None:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Users VALUES(?, ?)", (login, password))
        con.commit()

        print("Успешная регистрация!\nЧерез 2 секунды вы будете перенаправлены в окно авторизации")
        time.sleep(2)
        autorize()
    else:
        print("Данный аккаунт уже существует\nХотите войти?")
        answer = input("Да/нет - ")
        if answer == "Да" or answer == "да":
            autorize()
        elif answer == "Нет" or answer == "нет":
            registration()

action = input("Вход/Регистрация\n")

if action == "Вход" or action == "вход":
    autorize()
elif action == "Регистрация" or action == "регистрация":
    registration()

con.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего ошибка в этой строке.

```
cur.execute("SELECT Login FROM Users WHERE Login = login")
```

Тут ты сравниваешь логин со строкой `"login"`, а не с параметром `login` полученным ранее.

Исправить это можно так:

```
cur.execute("SELECT Login FROM Users WHERE Login = ?", (login,))
```

Comment: Документация по методу: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробовал, но выдает синтаксическую ошибку:
"sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error"

Comment: Не `%s`, а `?`. И у него не строкой сравнивается, а скорее всего с полем этой же таблицы

Comment: А, да, ошибся, это документация для mysql, а у тебя sqlite. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Исправил, проверил, всё работает, большое спасибо, ребята!